# proxy "localhost" in Codesandbox.io React Project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package.json, codesandbox

I want to use spring boot rest services running in my local computer in codesandbox.io React Project.
to do this in my local system I edit my package.json with
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"

but what should I do to use my local API in codesandbox?

Comment: Can you provide the codesandbox.io `url` for your project if it's not private?

Comment: yeah...sure. but this is not original one but that one explains what I want 
https://codesandbox.io/s/zlrznn6m2p

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to call a spring boot api running on your local machine from within a codesandbox app.

If the react app is running on codesandbox it will not be able to "see" your local machine.

A way to achieve this would be to deploy your spring boot app to another cloud service like Heroku who offer a free option. You will also need to allow cross origin requests in your spring boot api because request will be coming from the codesandbox domain.

Answer (score 1):

one option to expose local machine could be by using ngrok